# Can I Claim Social Security If I Live Abroad?

Tags: united-states, social-security

Can I claim SS if I live abroad?  Specifically in France or Germany.  Does the answer depend on citizenship?  I am both a US and UK citizen at the moment. I currently reside in California.

I am eligible - I am 60 and have been paying the taxes since 1985.  I receive letters from the government every year or two telling me how much my monthly would be if I retire at 62, 65, etc.

I live in the US now and have done all the time I've been paying social security taxes.

In case it's not clear, I am referring in this question to the Social Security program of the US government intended to help older people that was started in F. D. Roosevelt's administration.

The duplicate pointed to by littleadv contains a link that does answer the question although the questions are not exact duplicates as one explicitly refers to non-citizens whereas this question refers to citizens.  Regardless, thanks for marking it as a duplicate as it led to the correct answer.

Comment: So are you in the UK or US? Please put a country tag.

Comment: Curious - so long as he's earned his social security benefit, does the country he retires in matter?

Comment: I marked this duplicate despite the other question asking about non-citizens because the answer is essentially the same.